# lightning:recordEditForm | Some input fields not being displayed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-inputfield

I'm trying to create a new form for a custom Object in salesforce.
This is my form Code:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="MyFormId"
                                  objectApiName="MyCustomObject__c"     
                                  onload="{!c.handleOnload}"
                                  onsubmit="{!c.handleOnSubmit}"
                                  onsuccess="{!c.handleOnSuccess}"
                                  onerror="{!c.handleOnError}"
                                  class="slds-card__body_inner">

            <lightning:card iconName="utility:edit"  title="Edit" >                
                <div class = "slds-p-horizontal_large" >

                    <lightning:messages/>
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="MarketAccount__c"/>
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="TotalAmount__c"/>
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Active__c"/>
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="LoanFunnel__c"/>
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Event__c"/>

                    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-end slds-p-vertical_medium"> 
                        <lightning:button variant="brand"   label="Cancel" />
                        <lightning:button variant="brand"   label="Submit" type="submit" />
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </lightning:card>

        </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Here is the Issue:
The form is missing some fields and im not sure the reason:

[image]

I'm expecting 5 fields but there are being showing only 3.

MarketAccount__c  type: lookup

TotalAmount__c type: number

Active__c type: checkbox

LoanFunnel__c type: lookup

Event__c type: lookup

Comment: Does the User accessing the component has access to the missing fields? `lightning:recordEditForm` honors FLS, so you may like to verify that.

Comment: as @JayantDas says check Field level security for totalAmount__c & Active__c fields

Comment: Thank you guys! you were right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! 
It was a field accessibility issue.

The fields: 
`MarketAccount__c` and `Active__c` missed the user accessibility configs when them were moved with a changeset to my sandbox.

It was solved adding user rights following [this steps](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=modifying_field_access_settings.htm&type=5)

Comment: You should add more details to the answer viz., explaining which fields were missing FLS and how you made it to work to make this answer a more comprehensive and complete.

Comment: Done, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason that cause issues with lightning:inputField is if you don't **fill the recordTypeId property of the lightning:recordEditForm, in case that exist more than one**.

Docu of "lightning:recordEditForm":

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/specification